# Turn off separator lines between specific UITableViewCells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is there anyway I can programmatically turn off the lines between certain cells in `UITableView`? For example, if I want to turn off the lines between the first and second `UITableViewCell` but leave the line between the third and fourth `UITableViewcell`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do this. However you can add a separator yourself as a subview and hide/remove for cells where you want them to be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You can move it so far that it will be hidden.

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) 
{
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 1000, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this method out and see how well it works.

Comment: "You can use this property to add space between the current cell’s contents and the left and right edges of the table. ... Only the left and right inset values are respected"

Comment: This isn't an ideal solution. Your best bet is to set `separatorStyle` on `UITableView` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`. And add your own separator as subview in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` See Jeff Ames answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this with the default separator. You need to hide the default one and then create `UIImageView` (You can use other view also like `UIView`, `UILabel` etc) object for separator functionality.

**I have used `UIImageView` as a separator because if in near future you required an image as a separator than it will be easy.**

A sample code to demonstrate this:

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView     *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];

    // Hide default seperator.
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma mark
#pragma mark UITableView datasource methods

//---------------------------------------------------------------

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 15;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellIdentifier%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"Hello"];

    if (indexPath.row > 1) {

        UIImageView *seperatorLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height - 1, cell.frame.size.width, 1)];
        [seperatorLine setBackgroundColor:self.tableView.separatorColor];
        [cell addSubview:seperatorLine];
    }
    return cell;
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

@end
```

**Note:** Observe object `cellIdentifier`. I have created unique cell identifier, because if you specified here `static` it will use same identifier for all cell. And after scrolling table view you will see separator on first and second cell also.